# Python Unicode encodings

Tags: python, unicode

Is it possible to print Japanese text without changing the system locale on linux?
the locale that the Japanese prints on is `ja_JP.UTF-8` . But if I set it to `decode('utf-8')` it will show all weird.

I'm doing: `jp_string.decode("GB18030").encode("utf-8")`

Here is an image:
[image]

Comment: By "print" you probably mean writing to a terminal window.  Don't forget that the terminal window must support the characters as well.  Your screen-shot appears to show a Microsoft window.  Are you using putty or something like that?  Check the emulator's settings.

Comment: I am using putty but my system locale is japanese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be missing some of the neccessary fonts to print Japanese text, in particular UTF-8 appears to be working correctly, just some of the glyphs are missing.

if you can, install, but don't select the japanses locale, that will get you the needed fonts without breaking your current locale.

In windows if you visit some japanese web pages you get a prompt to install the missing font package.

Comment: When I set the server locale to ja_JP.UTF-8 it works. But I don't want to do that, is there a font pack in debian? I know in ubuntu its language-pack-en or ja

Comment: what happens if you set it to en-US.UTF-8

Comment: What do you mean by sent?

Answer (score 1):

It worked. The answer is provided by Jason, by setting the locale to `en_US.UTF-8` it displays perfect. Thanks a lot guys. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can print japanese text without changing your locale if you use some utf-8 locale which supports all Unicode characters. If your locale does not use `utf-8` (see the output of `locale` command) then 
you could change what character encoding is used for I/O by setting `PYTHONIOENCODING` envvar:

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python your-script.py
```

Make sure the text is stored as Unicode (`unicode` type on Python 2, `str` (the default) type on Python 3). Print Unicode strings directly, don't encode them to bytes manually.